# Base image and incremental backup solutions

Tags: osx, offline, backup, encryption

I am looking for two different backup solutions.

Below are the baseline requirements for the ideal solutions:

- MacBook PRO / macOS support
- All backups are locally encrypted
- One should make a backup and not automatically upload to the cloud
- Scheduled runs
- Capable of sending to various destinations (cloud, USB, a network solution eg.)

However, I want to solve two different problems:

1) to have a base image (OS + necessary programs installed) for quick restores
2) data backups of important pieces of data

If even those requirements are not implementable, a partial solution is very welcome as well.